# Flutter : Where is the title of Material App used?

Tags: dart, flutter

The flutter **app name** is shown by the **package name**, the **AppBar title** is shown on the **AppBar of the home page**, so where does the title `MaterialApp(title: 'Rectangle App',);` is used in flutter projects.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Rectangle App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Rectangle App Home Page'),
        ),
        body: HelloRectangle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [official doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/title.html):

> A one-line description used by the device to identify the app for the
>   user.
>
> On Android the titles appear above the task manager's app snapshots
>   which are displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button. On
>   iOS this value cannot be used. CFBundleDisplayName from the app's
>   Info.plist is referred to instead whenever present, CFBundleName
>   otherwise.

**1. Useful for the Android only.**

**2. On iOS this value cannot be used.**

Comment: Technically it *CAN* be *USED*. Nothing blows up or anything, it doesn't even give you a warning, because *Write Once*, and all that, but it **yields no value / has no effect** what so ever, so the point for its existence is just to avoid the need to have separate source files for separate platforms. Kinda the idea behind Flutter in the first place if I've gotten it right.

Answer (score 50):

This is a good question. Below is the the explanation of how it is used:

> A one-line description used by the device to identify the app for the user.
>
> On Android the titles appear above the task manager's app snapshots
>   which are displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button.
>   Similarly, on iOS the titles appear in the App Switcher when the user
>   double presses the home button.

So in short:

- On Android: it is used in Recent apps
- On iOS: it is used in App switcher

**Update 11th Feb, 2020:**

The document is updated (I don't know exactly the updated time)

> A one-line description used by the device to identify the app for the
>   user. On Android the titles appear above the task manager's app
>   snapshots which are displayed when the user presses the "recent apps"
>   button. On iOS this value cannot be used. CFBundleDisplayName from the
>   app's Info.plist is referred to instead whenever present, CFBundleName
>   otherwise. To provide a localized title instead, use
>   [onGenerateTitle].

So this value has no effect on iOS

Comment: Not true for iOS! There is no way to change the App Display Name except from the info.plist.

Comment: How come this is still considered the "right answer" when it is not correct? This line is simply not correct: "Similarly, on iOS the titles appear in the App Switcher when the user double presses the home button."

Comment: What's wrong with that line? I picked it from the official documentation

Comment: @PhucTran What's wrong is that it is wrong. The title property isn't used on iOS. Quote from the MaterialApp class documentation: "On Android the titles appear above the task manager's app snapshots which are displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button. On iOS this value cannot be used. CFBundleDisplayName from the app's Info.plist is referred to instead whenever present, CFBundleName otherwise."

Comment: Okay. I just checked the document again and update my answer. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @PhucTran Here is the commit, from Sep 20, 2018: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22011/commits/950c40615bb70d67bc35b2c843283a2d5ebe3232

Comment: So can I make an if/else statement and change the language of the app? Or I should stick to one string only through my app

Comment: I am a newbie in Flutter, For iOS simulator/real iPhone this title didn't show anywhere. for android, I can't see anywhere in "recent apps" too. - maybe "Pixel_3a_API_30_x86" update this feature. - it's my observation, so I comment over here, rather than add an answer.

Answer (score 12):

In "Flutter for Web", it's used in browser-tabs, which corresponds to the web app's 'title' property.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:
To be complete, now that Flutter is being implemented on more platforms, like the mentioned web platform and the upcoming desktop support my current answer is probably no longer adequate.

The *title* property of the *MaterialApp* class is still used as originally described:
 
*A one-line description used by the device to identify the app for the user.*

On Android the 'title' property appears above the task manager's app snapshots which are displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button or trigger the same functionality using a gesture.

**On iOS this value has no effect.**

'CFBundleDisplayName' from the app's 'Info.plist' is referred to instead whenever present and 'CFBundleName' otherwise. This is still the case.

You can open the iOS module in Xcode to change the value in Info.plist to change what is displayed on iOS.

This is also true when using the *CupertinoApp* class on iOS.

In other contexts, the title property is meant to be used by the 
"OS task switcher". so what that means in practice as Flutter gets implemented on more platforms remains to see.
But as mentioned, the value is passed to a browser-tab's title when used with Flutter for the web, and to the window title when used on the (as of this date) experimental macOS and Linux desktop platforms and as the app title when using the OS app switchers like ⌘ + Tab on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: Elements.getThemeData(),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

when you put the app background title is demonstrated.
A page title is shown as 'Flutter Demo Home Page'