# Can someone please show me a screenshot of what 「title」property in MaterialApp does in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

what does the 「title: "test of title"」property under MaterialApp do? can someone please share some screenshots?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "test of title", // what does this do?
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : Where is the title of Material App used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615006/flutter-where-is-the-title-of-material-app-used)

Answer (score 0):

When you see your app in recent apps of your device, title is shown as the application name.

Comment: It does not show in mine. 
here is a screenshot of what it looks on my device:
https://ibb.co/0Dh2N9v

Answer (score 0):

MaterialApp `title` property define your app title within the device.

Here you go.

[image: This is the title of your application]

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+click` will show you this

```
  /// {@template flutter.widgets.widgetsApp.title}
  /// A one-line description used by the device to identify the app for the user.
  ///
  /// On Android the titles appear above the task manager's app snapshots which are
  /// displayed when the user presses the "recent apps" button. On iOS this
  /// value cannot be used. `CFBundleDisplayName` from the app's `Info.plist` is
  /// referred to instead whenever present, `CFBundleName` otherwise.
  /// On the web it is used as the page title, which shows up in the browser's list of open tabs.
  ///
  /// To provide a localized title instead, use [onGenerateTitle].
  /// {@endtemplate}
  final String title;
```